# PHP: Make member object replace itself

Tags: php, class, object, replace

Ok, this is a weird one, I'm aware of that, but I'd like to know if it is someway possible.

The goal is to make a member object of a class replace itself with another object.

```
class A
{
  public $object;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->object = new B($this); // added reference to A
  }
}

class B
{
  private $caller;    // reference to A
  private $myobject;

  public function __construct($caller)
  {
    $this->myobject = new C();
    $this->caller = $caller;
  }

  public function replace()
  {
    // here goes the topic code...
  }
}

class C
{
  // whatever...
}


$A = new A();
$A->object->replace();
// after calling the "replace" method, $A->object becomes the B's child C instance
```

I know that doing something like

```
$A->object->replace($A);
```

and in B class

```
public function replace($class)
{
  $class->object=$this->myobject;
}
```

would be the easiest way, but I would like to avoid this reference pass everytime...also I wouldn't had ask you if I was looking for the easy way ;)

Any kind of trick is welcome.

Thank you experts.

Comment: If you give us your real example of what you're trying to do, we could suggest you a nice design pattern. But this sounds very odd.

Comment: No clue on what you are asking really - what do you mean by _replace_? Can't you just put whatever you want in `$A -> object` field?

Comment: I would, but actually I have no particular pattern to achieve or example to show, I am just struggling on it trying to find if it is possible at all, or if the shown easy way is really the only one possible. Yes, it's odd, it's a challenge :)

Comment: @moonwave99 in short I'd like to know if it's is possible to take the relation A->B->C to A->C working from B, _replace_ stands for _remove it from the chain_ somewhat...hope I explain what I mean. Could be useful to make B as a wrapper class for example.

Comment: The only way this can work is when B holds a reference to A. In your example this is not the case so there is no way for B to find the A containing this particular B.

Comment: @Dan Yes, I see your point, A reference in B is required. I'll add it to the post.

Comment: Well then your replace method only needs to set $caller->object=$this->myobject; Or am I missing something?

Comment: That's it. Now is pretty straightforward. Problem was trying to get it work without that A reference in B, but seems quite impossible that way.